# T_STRING error even when I don't have any PHP code, just the open close PHP markings

Tags: php

Yes, another one of these T_STRING errors...but hopefully this one is different.

Here is all the code I have on my page:

```
<?php


?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 


</urlset>
```

As you can probably see, I'm trying to do a sitemap for my site.  But I didn't put anything on it and I already have a

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ..../sitemap.php on line 4
```

Which points to the end of PHP code marking ?>

Any input much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Smells like [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is switched on. Disable it. What happens if you remove line 4?

Comment: I think you are right, but how do I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<?php

   echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> ';
?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 


</urlset>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/4a51c

problem are these  php tags, open-short-tags are probably allowed on your server

Comment: open-short-tags is probably allowed on your server

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to include/require XML in PHP.
Proper handling of XML should always use XML handling function/class like

- [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)
- [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)